# Wordpress multisite change language

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I want to change site language through cookies. 
As I have multisite, so define('WPLANG') is not working in wp-config.php.

So I added hook to filter "locale". But still not working... What to do ?

p.s I have translated .po & .mo files in "wp-content/languages/" folder.

The code in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'locale', 'set_my_locale', 9999 );
function set_my_locale( $lang ){
$lang = "fr_FR";
return $lang;
}
```

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE:** Created as a plugin and all worked like a charm.

Comment: "So I added hook to filter "locale"" - AFAICS that is what you're supposed to do. Can you debug `load_default_textdomain` in `wp-includes/l10n.php` somehow to see what it's actually doing? It might also be worth checking your filter is being hit, i.e. it's being loaded early enough, but again AFAICS it should be if that's in either your theme or a plugin.

Comment: (Incidentally the equivalent of WPLANG for multisite is setting an option WPLANG in the site table, and the wp-config WPLANG is going away in WordPress 4.0 anyway.)

Comment: I guess it loads much earlier and in functions.php its not working ...

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was reading it wrong: `wp-settings` runs `load_default_textdomain` after the plugins have loaded but before the theme is loaded. So you could put that in a plugin?

Comment: its a good idea i will try it and update you.

Comment: It worked like a charm. I created plugin and its finally worked.